# Select all rows from a table that is not in the current query result

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
dispensaries_list_new d JOIN cities c ON d.city = c.city_name
AND d.state = c.state_code
```

I want to take all rows excluding the result of this query. I've tried putting not equal to. But returns error data.

Comment: from which table..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get dispensaries that *don't* have a matching city, then you can use `left join` and `where`:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM dispensaries_list_new d LEFT JOIN
     cities c
     ON d.city = c.city_name AND d.state = c.state_code
WHERE c.city_name IS NULL;
```

Actually, if you want cities with no dispensary, then you can use inverse logic -- basically reversing the order of the joins:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cities c LEFT JOIN
     dispensaries_list_new d 
     ON d.city = c.city_name AND d.state = c.state_code
WHERE d.city IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hey bro.. i think you misunderstood my question... see i have 5128 rows in my table. i got 3033 as my result. i want the rest 2095 rows as my result.